# implications of padding a fuzzy hashing algorithm with a fixed buffer

Tags: hash, md5, fuzzy

What are the implications of padding a buffer and passing it to a fuzzy hashing implementations (ssdeep/sdhash).

I got 2 buffers that I would like to check for similarity, however, they are very short and these tools will not run on them.

Buffer A: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Buffer B: AAAAAAA**B**AAAAAAA

As you can see they are very similar.

If I pad both of them with 0 (page aligned):

Buffer A: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA00000000000000....0000 (4096 bytes of '0')
Buffer B: AAAAAAA**B**AAAAAAA00000000000000....0000 (4096 bytes of '0')

The similarity score is 15.

When i tried to pad them with random data (both buffers was added the same random data of course).
The similarity score is 86.

What are the implications of both padding techniques that i used? should i use them?